# How to evaluate a regression model?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, artificial-intelligence, regression, linear-regression

I have a dataset with 190 samples.
I'm training a regression model, using k-fold cross validation.
I'm using r squared form measuring the performance do the model.

However, sometimes, depending on the randomization process of the cross validation process, the r squared is very bad. This happens because form a few samples, the results of the regression are very far from the expected ones. But, for most of the samples, the regression is very good.

I think that, sometimes, in the cross validation process, I'm not including in the training set samples from teh same probability distribution of the samples with bad results.

My question is: how can I evaluate my model fairly, in this situation?

Comment: Good question! But since it's not directly programming related, I don't think it belongs here but rather on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Please check ["Which site?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in) for general issues.  I recommend moving this to the **stats** site.